# MongoDb count returns different number than count of records

Tags: mongodb, meteor

While I am new to mongoDb, I just cannot see where I am doing a mistake:

```
MyDb.find().count() // returns 120
let data = MyDb.find()
let records = []
for (let a of data)
  //adding records
  records.push(a)
}
console.log(records.length) // result: 125
```

What am I not seeing here? How can I get more records using the iteration through the data?

Comment: Can you please share more info or screenshot, kind of compass screenshot, etc so that we can identify.

Answer (score 0):

The following line returns a Mongo.Cursor:

```js
let data = MyDb.find()
```

The cursor itself is only a "pointer" to the data. If you want to iterate over the cursors data you should use `.forEach`:

```js
MyDb.find().count() // returns 120
let cursor = MyDb.find()
let records = []
cursor.forEach(doc => {
  //adding records
  records.push(doc)
})
console.log(records.length) // result: 120
```

However, you can easily access the data using `fetch` as Array:

```js
const cursor = MyDb.find()
cursor.count() // returns 120
let records = cursor.fetch()
console.log(records.length) // result: 120
```

Read more at:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor

https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html

https://university.meteor.com/